# Disable throwing error message in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using the `$.jgrid.del` mehtod in my application. I'm clear about the `errorTextFormat` and now, i just want the function not to throw the error. Just do nothing since i have my customized error popup. Its now like throwing two popup with the errors.

I tried the following code and it didn't work. Still throwing the error.

//Code:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.del, {
    ajaxDelOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
    mtype: "DELETE",
    reloadAfterSubmit: false,
    jqModal: false,
    serializeDelData: function (postdata) {
        return "";
    },
    errorTextFormat: function (data) {
             ThrowCustError(data);
             return [true, '', ''];
            //return data.statusText;         
    }
});
```

How to disable `errorTextFormat` from throwing the error popup.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback `errorTextFormat` can only change the text of the message displayed after Delete. If you want interpret the server response as successful you should use `afterSubmit` callback instead:

```js
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.del, {
    ajaxDelOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
    mtype: "DELETE",
    reloadAfterSubmit: false,
    jqModal: false,
    serializeDelData: function (postdata) {
        return "";
    },
    afterSubmit: function (jqXhr) {
        // you can analyse jqXhr here and return the following
        // to ignore 
        return [true]; // or return [true,""];
    }
});
```